# Can I set up the printer in Word to print in black even if the file has colours?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, printer, printing, microsoft-word-2013

How can I set up the printer in Word to print in black even if the file has colours?
I noticed if the file has coloured parts, they are not printed.
My printer, Canon MP190, has only black ink.
One way is to change all the font to black. But is it a more direct method, from settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sorts of settings are generally available via the printer driver/software instead of the app itself.

In Word's Print dialog if you click on Printer Properties, you should see an option to print in grayscale if your printer supports it. Select that and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such options of choice to be found in the standard interface for the Canon MP190. It prints using both color and B&W.

Comment: I ask about Word; what do you mean by standard interface?

Answer (score 0):

I have Microsoft Office 2016 on my HP laptop. With my Epson printer I can only print out black and white pages instead of colors. Before when you hit printer properties is would allow you to print color or black and white but it doesn't do that here.

Comment: I have an Epson WF 3640 printer